# How to create a button that shows some inputs only when clicked/toggled?

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to create the exact same button (visually dropdown) "price range", like the one in this website: https://dubai.dubizzle.com/en/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/

This button:
[image]

```css
/* CSS */

.button_wrapper {
  background: white none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 48px;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px 6px 0px 12px;
  border: 0px none;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lnhPTn {
  position: absolute;
  background: white none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  color: rgb(182, 184, 185);
  margin-top: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(43, 45, 46);
  height: auto;
  padding: 16px;
}

.kFCjgJ {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gacQrk {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.43;
  color: rgb(43, 45, 46);
}

.fmQggb {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(182, 184, 185);
  height: 48px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

..jaNqhG {
  border: 0px none;
  width: 8px;
  margin: 0px 6px 18px;
  height: 1px;
  background: rgb(43, 45, 46) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<!-- BUTTON STARTS HERE -->
<div class="button_wrapper">
  <button type="button" class="button_price">
        <span class="button_span">Any</span>
            <svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path d="M6 9l6 6 6-6"></path>
            </svg>
    </button>
  <div class="lnhPTn">
    <div class="bkwgFh">
      <div class="kFCjgJ">
        <label class="gacQrk" for="min">
                Min
                <input class="fmQggb" type="number" step="1000" min="0" max="100000000" id="min">
            </label>
        <span class="jaNqhG"></span>


        <label class="gacQrk" for="max">
                Max
                <input class="fmQggb" type="number" step="1000" min="0" max="100000000" id="max">
            </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- BUTTON ENDS HERE -->
```

How to show the div below the button (the div which contain the inputs) only when clicking/toggling the button and automatically close when something else is clicked/toggled (like for instance the next button or search)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution in 3 step-

1. Add `onclick="document.querySelector('.lnhPTn').style.display=document.querySelector('.lnhPTn').style.display=='block'?'none':'block'"` attribute on your button.
2. Add

```
<script>
  window.onclick=function (e){
  var buttonPrice =document.querySelector(".button_price");
  var mainDiv=document.querySelector(".lnhPTn");
  var inputs=document.querySelectorAll(".lnhPTn input")
  console.log(inputs.length)
    if(e.target!=buttonPrice && e.target!=mainDiv &&  e.target!=inputs[0] && e.target!=inputs[1]){
      mainDiv.style.display="none";
    }
  }

</script>
```

at end of body tag.

3. In css set main div's display to none.

So your final code will look like

```css
button_wrapper {
  background: white none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 48px;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px 6px 0px 12px;
  border: 0px none;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lnhPTn {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  background: white none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  color: rgb(182, 184, 185);
  margin-top: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(43, 45, 46);
  height: auto;
  padding: 16px;
}

.kFCjgJ {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gacQrk {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.43;
  color: rgb(43, 45, 46);
}

.fmQggb {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(182, 184, 185);
  height: 48px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

..jaNqhG {
  border: 0px none;
  width: 8px;
  margin: 0px 6px 18px;
  height: 1px;
  background: rgb(43, 45, 46) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<!-- BUTTON STARTS HERE -->
<div class="button_wrapper">
  <button type="button" class="button_price" onclick="document.querySelector('.lnhPTn').style.display=document.querySelector('.lnhPTn').style.display=='block'?'none':'block'">
        <span class="button_span">Any</span>
            <svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path d="M6 9l6 6 6-6"></path>
            </svg>
    </button>
  <div class="lnhPTn">
    <div class="bkwgFh">
      <div class="kFCjgJ">
        <label class="gacQrk" for="min">
                Min
                <input class="fmQggb" type="number" step="1000" min="0" max="100000000" id="min">
            </label>
        <span class="jaNqhG"></span>


        <label class="gacQrk" for="max">
                Max
                <input class="fmQggb" type="number" step="1000" min="0" max="100000000" id="max">
            </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- BUTTON ENDS HERE -->
<script>
  window.onclick=function (e){
  var buttonPrice =document.querySelector(".button_price");
  var mainDiv=document.querySelector(".lnhPTn");
  var inputs=document.querySelectorAll(".lnhPTn input")
    if(e.target!=buttonPrice && e.target!=mainDiv &&  e.target!=inputs[0] && e.target!=inputs[1]){
      mainDiv.style.display="none";
    }
  }

</script>
```

Here's a working jsfiddle with this code
https://jsfiddle.net/o48ps293/

Comment: I'm not looking for a drop down option list, I am looking to have a button that will allow  the user to insert a range price, as you can clearly see from the link I have sent as well as the image and code.

Comment: if that's what you're looking for, then you can make two input boxes, one for lower limit and the other for upper limit and scan through the array or whatever for the suitable products

Comment: @SkylerX if you want that then I have updated the answer, to solve your problem in just 3 steps

Comment: @factouch wow, your code is complete and working

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do what you wanted

```js
  const buttonPrice = document.querySelector(".button_price");
  const  boxWrap = document.querySelector(".boxWrap");
  let displayed =false;
buttonPrice.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
if(!displayed){
boxWrap.style.display="inline";displayed =true;}
else{boxWrap.style.display="none";displayed =false;}
    
})
```

```css
.button_wrapper {
  background: white none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 48px;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px 6px 5px 12px;
  border: 0px none;
  width: 400px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.boxWrap {
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
  background: white none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  color: rgb(182, 184, 185);
  margin-top: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(43, 45, 46);
  height: auto;
  padding: 16px;
}

.kFCjgJ {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gacQrk {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.43;
  color: rgb(43, 45, 46);
}

.fmQggb {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(182, 184, 185);
  height: 48px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.jaNqhG {
  border: 0px none;
  width: 8px;
  margin: 0px 6px 18px;
  height: 1px;
  background: rgb(43, 45, 46) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<!-- BUTTON STARTS HERE -->  <button type="button" class="button_price">
        <span class="button_span">Any</span>
            <svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path d="M6 9l6 6 6-6"></path>
            </svg>
    </button>
<div class="button_wrapper">

  <div class="boxWrap">
    <div class="bkwgFh">
      <div class="kFCjgJ">
        <label class="gacQrk" for="min">
                Min
                <input class="fmQggb" type="number" step="1000" min="0" max="100000000" id="min">
            </label>
        <span class="jaNqhG"></span>


        <label class="gacQrk" for="max">
                Max
                <input class="fmQggb" type="number" step="1000" min="0" max="100000000" id="max">
            </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- BUTTON ENDS HERE -->
```

Comment: Can you please advise where is the code supposed to go and what is it most importantly? I currently only know Html and CSS.

Comment: Hi SkylerX !
1)I recommand to put the div of the 2 inputs outside the button and do not wrapper inside it
2) then this dive that i named it as boxWrap i added to its style display:none; 
3) i changed the css of .button_price 
4) i added a javascript code that will handle your click to display your hidden div and it will change the display: none to display: inline.
Thats All

Comment: Hi Mohammer rezzouq, I made your code work with Jquery and activating it at the top in the head, but the input divs remains open after I inserted the numbers I want and they do not close after I click anything outside the div Can you please rectify the code so that It will go back to hidden after clicking anything outside the div?.

Comment: My code works without jquery library requirement, it's a native javascript ES6 code

Comment: If you dont have an idea about javascript so it is to handle events , here in your example the click on button is a click event so we can catch this event and do and execute something after this click , what we execute here is the js code, just put it inside <script> the javascript code here </script> and put this script tag before </body> tag

Comment: Thanks Mohammeq rezzouq, the code works but the div remains open after having inserted the numbers, not like the one shown in the example. Can you please tell me how can I make sure that the div goes back to hidden after I have inserted the inputs and clicked outside the div?

Comment: it is not hiding on clicking anywhere else.(i.e. onblur)

Answer (score 0):

Found the shortest solution but with javascript  to make hidden or visible a div.

```css
.hidden>div {
  display: none;
}

.visible>div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="text_container" id="some_id">
  <button>Visible</button>
  <div>
    <!--div that we want to hide-->
    <form id="some_form" style="visibility: hidden;">
      <!--style="visibility: hidden;"-->
      <input type="number">
      <input type="number">
    </form>
  </div>
  <!--end div I want to hide-->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var theButton = document.getElementById('some_id');
  theButton.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('some_form').style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: note it is not working completely as on again clicking the button or anywhere else on screen doesn't hide it. check factouch 's solution